# Erasing elements from generic (void *) list in C

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, function-pointers

I'm writing a generic doubly linked list in C.

```
typedef struct ListNode {
    void *data;
    struct ListNode *prev;
    struct ListNode *next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct List {
    struct ListNode *head;
    struct ListNode *tail;
} List;
```

Inserting element into list is done simply by

```
listNode->data = data;
```

where listNode is some list element, and data is a data to be inserted. So I'm doing a shallow copy. Now, when I want to delete something from list, I want to be able to perform a deep copy, so I have a function performing deep delete of objects I pass to the list. I would like to pass a pointer to this function as a parameter to function deleting member of list. An example is given below.

```
typedef struct Object {
    int *ptr;
} Object;

void removeObject(Object *object) {
    free(object->ptr);
    free(object);
}

void removeListNodeFromList(List *list, ListNode *listNode,
                               void (*removeEntry)(void *data)) {
    // Code handling removing listNode from list
    // ...

    removeEntry(listNode->data);
    free(listNode);
}

void fun() {
    List *list = NULL;
    ListNode *listNode = NULL;
    // Some code giving specific value to list and listNode
    // ...

    removeListNodeFromList(list, listNode, removeObject);
}
```

This code won't compile because (the last line of code) removeObject is incompatible with removeEntry. How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the function signatures compatible, your `removeObject` must accept a generic pointer and cast it appropriately:

```c
void removeObject(void *vptr) {
    Object *object = (Object *)vptr;
    free(object->ptr);
    free(object);
}
```

Comment: In C you can drop the cast and just do `Object *object = vptr;`.